# Joomla! 2.5 checking code for deprecated classes / methods

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How can I check my extensions for deprecated Joomla! API code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is to be done on a development machine, not on the production website!**

The most basic way to check for deprecated code is to enable the **System Debug Plugin** and to enable the **option "Log deprecated API".**

[image: Log deprecated API]

After this in logs/deprecated.php you will find the entries.

Now, there will be lots of deprecated code loged and you need to identify it in your code.

---

A complementary option would be to use an IDE like Eclipse + PDT where you can get this info while you are coding:

[image]